# performance in oracle database

Tags: database, oracle

I have a table named cars in which there are three columns: 
car_id, car_name, car_model
car_id is the primary key

There are two databases which contain the same table.

In one database: car table has 8700455 records
In the other database: car table has 9036113 records
So, second database has 335658 more records

Now I fire a query in both the database:

```
SELECT objs1_defaultNCObjectMapping.car_id id 
FROM cars objs1_defaultNCObjectMapping 
WHERE UPPER(objs1_defaultNCObjectMapping.car_name) LIKE '%STARTWTH100_T0_00000%' ESCAPE '\';
```

In both the databases I get the same result of 100 rows.

But the problem is with the execution time, the database with more rows takes longer time.

```
Explain plan where performance is good[Smaller Table]
--------------
  LEVEL,         PLAN,                          ROWS,       COST,   PREDICATES
1   SELECT STATEMENT (OPTIMIZER=ALL_ROWS)   25000000    112744  [NULL]
2    INDEX (FULL SCAN) "XIF34NC_OBJECTS"    25000000    112744  filter(UPPER("NAME") LIKE '%STARTWTH100\_T0\_00000%' ESCAPE '\' AND UPPER("NAME") IS NOT NULL)
```

### Explain plan where performance is bad[Larger Table]

```
LEVEL,  PLAN,                                ROWS,      COST,   PREDICATES
    1   SELECT STATEMENT (OPTIMIZER=ALL_ROWS)   25000000    112875  [NULL]
    2     INDEX (FULL SCAN) "XIF34NC_OBJECTS"   25000000    112875  filter(UPPER("NAME") LIKE '%STARTWTH100\_T0\_00000%' ESCAPE '\' AND UPPER("NAME") IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Update your question with your code, it's unreadable in the comments. And ask a question too.

Comment: Is that explain plan from the query against the larger table?  What is the explain plan from the query against the smaller table?  How much more time is the longer one taking?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak i have added both the plans

Comment: Are those the execution plans from the posted query?  I see a NOT NULL filter reference in the plan but not in your query.

Comment: `INDEX (FULL SCAN)` in both cases instead of `FAST FULL SCAN`.  Are you sure you posted the whole query and did not edit out anything you thought wasn't important like an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: there was no order by @Matthew McPeak

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Is the query taking long time due to this reason : In one database: car table has 8700455 records In the other database: car table has 9036113 records So, second database has 335658 more records . Even though both the table has car named ford with only 100 rows

Comment: Yes, that would make it take about 4% longer, give or take.  You never indicated how much slower the "bad" database is than the "good" one.